# Is there any difference in time complexity for mean shortest path length and diameter algorithms for a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, complexity-theory, graph-algorithm

For an undirected, unweighted graph, is there any difference in the time complexity of the algorithm to compute its average shortest path length vs, the complexity of the algorithm which computes the diameter of the graph, ie, the longest shortest path between two vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_%28graph_theory%29), to calculate the diameter of the graph, you should first find the all-pairs shortest path. After calculating the all-pairs shortest path, both algorithms reduce down to a O(V^2) calculation so their complexities are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read much literature on the subject but I suspect that the two are the same. However if there is a discrepancy, I'd say calculating the diameter of a graph might be asymptotically faster.

My algorithm for both would be to calculate all-pairs shortest path using Dijkstra's algorithm which runs in `V*(E+V*log(V))`. Then for the mean you would take the arithmetic average over all these values. I don't see a way you could speed this up.

However for calculating the diameter of a graph, there might be some clever tricks you can use to speed up this process. But as an upper bound, you can simply take the supremum over the all-pairs shortest path to get the diameter, which has the same run-time complexity as calculating the mean shortest path.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm only computes single-source shortest paths, not all-pairs shortest path.  A modification of Dijkstra's algorithm that computes all-pairs shortest paths is Johnson's algorithm, which can outperform Floyd-Warshall in some cases.

Comment: Just run Dijkstra's algorithm on all single sources. It's still faster than FW.

Comment: @tskuzzy- Johnson's algorithm essentially does this after preprocessing the graph to eliminate any negative-weight edges. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No there should not be any difference in the time complexity between the two.

You can find the longest path between two vertices by tweaking the shortest path algo.